# Are there Belief Revision techniques for quantified data?

Tags: lo.logic, ai.artificial-intel, knowledge-representation

Are there Belief Revision techniques that aren't based solely in formal logic propositions?

For example, if one agent believes the temperature for an area is 85 degrees and another believes the temperature is 79 degrees, is there a technique in the literature that has been proposed to to harmonize their beliefs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fuzzy Belief Revision](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.103.2676&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [Probabilistic Belief Revision](http://arno.unimaas.nl/show.cgi?fid=3677) are two flavours of Belief Revision that do not fall within the *formal logic propositions* characterisation of the field.